# In Typescript, how to assign a member of a discriminated type union to a generic type which expects that union

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm using React-Typescript.  I have a component which takes props like so:

```
type ComponentPropsType = {
    filterSet: FilterSet<Union>
}

type FilterSet<T> = {
    targetField: keyof T;
}

type Union = FirstType | SecondType;

type FirstType = {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    specificToFirst: string;
}

type SecondType = {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    specificToSecond: string;
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of Component:

```
export const Component = ({ filterSet }: ComponentPropsType) => {
    ...
}
```

When I attempt to invoke this component like so:

```
export const InvokerComponent = () => {
    const getFilterSet: FilterSet<FirstType> = () => 
        {targetField: "specificToFirst"}

    const filterSet: FilterSet<FirstType> = getFilterSet();

    return (
        <Component filterSet={filterSet} />  // TS ERROR HERE
    )
}
```

Typescript tells me:

```
Type FilterSet<FirstType> is not assignable to type FilterSet<Union> 
Type Union is not assignable to type FirstType
Type SecondType is missing the following properties from type FirstType: specificToFirst
```

My goal is to allow my component to accept a generic filterSet because I would like to restrict a field of filterSet to keyof the type passed in as the template.  That's not displayed in my example above, but I don't think it's important to the problem at hand.

Once we make it into Component, I don't really care whether FirstType or SecondType was passed in to generate the filterSet.  I want to restrict filterSet to `FilterSet<Union>` because I want the Union types well defined.  It's important to the definition of the filterSet, but not really the functionality of the component.

I hope I've given enough information to help solve this issue.  To restate the question:

In Typescript, how do I assign a member of a discriminated type union to a generic type which expects that union.

Comment: What is `FilterSet`? Include `Component` and `getFilterSet` please

Comment: @wonderflame added what you asked for.

Comment: `getFilterSet`....?

Comment: @wonderflame added an example

Comment: Does `keyof` behave contravariantly in typescript? This may be related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43608

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your union is not being distributed in `FilterSet`, which is why `FilterSet<Union` is evaluated as:

```
{
    targetField: "name" | "id";
}
```

What you actually need is something in the following format:

```
{
    targetField: "name";
} | {
    targetField: "id";
}
```

The reason why the fields that are specific for the `FirstType` and `SecondType` is a known issue with the `keyof` operator (probably there is a GitHub issue, but I couldn't find one).

The desired type can be achieved by referring to [distributive conditional types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type FilterSet<T> = T extends T
  ? {
      targetField: keyof T;
    }
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
// type Result = {
//   targetField: keyof FirstType;
// } | {
//   targetField: keyof SecondType;
// }
type Result = FilterSet<Union>
```

This is exactly what we need:

```
const getFilterSet = () => ({} as any);

export const InvokerComponent = () => {
  // The following funcntion simply returns a an object of type FilterSet<FirstType>
  const filterSet: FilterSet<FirstType> = getFilterSet();

  return (
    <Component filterSet={filterSet} /> // no error
  );
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAMWABsYkoBlJGAHgBUA+OAF44POEgAeLAHYATAM4jScOAH44AbyXLtMFFADmnBkkYyAXHADWSShEwiA3FuUBfLRalIAbqycVqtADCuJCeUjAACjhgcjwBQhpamEws7JwWDMysHNwAqlLAEFJ8Ti5+VDRw+YVSCQxQcjBxlQA+cBxoRTLNSOXx9Y09CZrKUiggSBaNUMBS+k7KwOZwUgCuIABGvlpyNGjAyWg8EAMwUzAzc6V9lR1dQ8IjK+OTcNOz81pLHutbUAtvPYHYBHCB3WTnS6fMrkCSQWBwTpSRpwYLgIpIcIJAAU6jgySyaXgLgsaNCmMi0ViAQAlEIBE8iDBVlBamtGIxruQkSjDDBMqkcji6YIBLiXHAUAoUFJKDS-HDoPAefAAJJSLwQaxQMkYrHCbEihlaAD0JpEAAtaJgIByIAB3D741ZSNDhGpvUBgRiUOBMlnIyWS2oQDYAKyQGDgdjgFVoAuynC4px6fC0KvxKUTZ3oWaJyeADSaAQEwj5CaJhr8yn9rLg2OccC4urCWDzOUE6gJgs4EpNAjNKwgYigOCgWnlpBh5EHccQSDkq2Yw1Ig+UugMRmAJmW1ls9hTAScg4lbU0a9jenL29MFj3MfB3SPq-NbjnyEXy+EFZyXGqRTTIA)